# Degraded raidz2 has forgotten a vdev during a motherboard loss. The drive is fine, but I am not able to replace

Tags: zfs

```
state: DEGRADED
status: One or more devices could not be used because the label is missing or
        invalid.  Sufficient replicas exist for the pool to continue
        functioning in a degraded state.
action: Replace the device using 'zpool replace'.
   see: http://zfsonlinux.org/msg/ZFS-8000-4J
  scan: scrub repaired 0B in 1 days 01:42:29 with 0 errors on Mon May 10 02:06:30 2021
config:

        NAME                                   STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
        enc6                                   DEGRADED     0     0     0
          raidz2-0                             DEGRADED     0     0     0
            ata-WDC_WD80EDAZ-11TA3A0_VGJXHDEK  ONLINE       0     0     0
            ata-WDC_WD80EFAX-68LHPN0_7SGJDASC  ONLINE       0     0     0
            ata-WDC_WD80EMAZ-00WJTA0_2SG3LEKJ  ONLINE       0     0     0
            9081516251822742376                UNAVAIL      0     0     0  was /dev/sda1
```

Did a little research and

```
            ##/dev/sdb ata-WDC_WD80EDAZ-11TA3A0_VGJXHDEK  ONLINE       0     0     0
            ##/dev/sdd ata-WDC_WD80EFAX-68LHPN0_7SGJDASC  ONLINE       0     0     0
            ##/dev/sdh ata-WDC_WD80EMAZ-00WJTA0_2SG3LEKJ  ONLINE       0     0     0
            ##/dev/sde 9081516251822742376                UNAVAIL      0     0     0  was /dev/sda1
```

Attempting to re-add the forgotten drive

```
sudo zpool add enc6 /dev/sde
invalid vdev specification
the following errors must be manually repaired:
/dev/sde1 is part of active pool 'enc6'
```

Trying to issue a replace

```
zpool replace enc6 9081516251822742376 /dev/sde1
invalid vdev specificationuse '-f' to override the following errors:/dev/sde1 is part of active pool        'enc6'
```

---

Update, tried some of the suggestions in @cas's answer & comments:

```
ls -lF /dev/disk/by-id | grep sde1$
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 May 24 12:52 ata-WDC_WD80EMAZ-00WJTA0_7HJW7G1F-part1 -> ../../sde1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 May 24 12:52 wwn-0x5000cca257e89101-part1 -> ../../sde1
```

Trying `zpool replace` with -f

```
sudo zpool replace enc6 -f 9081516251822742376 /dev/disk/by-id/ata-WDC_WD80EMAZ-00WJTA0_7HJW7G1F
invalid vdev specification
the following errors must be manually repaired:
/dev/disk/by-id/ata-WDC_WD80EMAZ-00WJTA0_7HJW7G1F-part1
```

Comment: did you also try rebooting to recovery mode and exporting/re-importing?   or physically removing the drive from the system and re-installing it?   BTW, what makes you certain that the drive is still good?

Comment: Also, you really should do a backup - immediately (in case something else happens to that pool), and regularly from now on.    Neither ZFS nor RAID are substitutes for regular backups, their redundancy allows the system to keep running while a dead drive is being replaced, but they do not protect against accidents or disasters.   If one more drive fails in your enc6 pool, you will lose **everything** on it if you do not have a backup.

Comment: BTW, when I said "physically remove the drive and re-install it", I meant reboot or power-cycle between those two actions, so that ZFS gets to see that the drive has been removed from the system.

Answer (score 0):

First, if you can, backup the `enc6` pool - e.g. by `zfs send`-ing it to a dataset on another pool.

If the pool is not currently in use (i.e. no open files), try:

```
zpool export enc6
zpool import -d /dev/disk/by-id/ enc6
```

Otherwise, try the `-f` option as suggested in the error message, but use the `/dev/disk/by-id` symlink instead of `/dev/sde1`.

First, run `ls -lF /dev/disk/by-id | grep sde1$` to identify the symlink.  Then:

```
zpool replace -f enc6 9081516251822742376 /dev/disk/by-id/XXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

Comment: if you have extra info, command output, etc, edit your question and add it there. i'm not even going to try to read that mess in a comment.    about the only thing i can tell from it is that you didn't use the `-f` option.    Try rebooting to recovery mode and doing a re-import as i suggested above.  if that fails, physically remove the drive and re-insert it. and if that fails, try using `zpool replace -f` as suggested by both my answer and the error message.